# Usage of transitive verbs

Tags: transitive-verbs, passive-voice

```
Transitive verbs when used in active voice take a direct object,that is to say not preceded by a preposition.However,transitive verbs when used passively take the preposition - to,by or from.This may appear normal for a native speaker of English language.The inquirer who is not  a native speaker of English language,the above mentioned construction appears to be a little odd.Because non-native speakers can hardly draw up any parallel between English language and their local language,when they come across such grammatical rules in English. That is Why the inquirer earlier posted the question "Is it mandatory to use the preposition-to,by or from with transitive verbs when used passively.For example: The bail out package was offered to Greece by the donor nations. The data for the study was abstracted from hospital records. She is married to a wealthy industrialist. The specific question being raised here is that, when a transitive verb used passively and while referring to the subject is it mandatory or optional to use the preposition – to ,by or from, as mentioned in the example sentences given above.
```

Comment: No. You only use prepositions when you need them. Just like with any word. If it was abstracted from records, you say "from records". If it was abstracted by records, you say "by records". If it was abstracted inside records, above records, within records, instead of records, between records, or after records, then you say "inside records", "above records", "within records", "instead of records", "between records", or "after records", respectively. If you don't know anything about any records, you don't mention any records at all. It was just abstracted. Period.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'nearly always'. The exception is 'to'. 'From' and 'by' are required.

Example

*The medal was given to him by the Queen.*

can be rewritten as:

*The medal was given him by the Queen.*

Some purists might argue against this - I find it acceptable.

Comment: When editing, I would not accept any text that used the second form. However, it seems to becoming more common in American usage, which seeps into all English usage via various media.